# Tool to find performance errors in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, logging, analytics, performance-testing

I'm trying to find performance problems in a Rails application.

I have 1 year of logs so I want to compare times for each action and see if there are strange things (like actions delays of more than 200ms for example) but I can't find any tool for this.

I've tried [Request Log Analyzer](https://github.com/wvanbergen/request-log-analyzer) and it's excelent to see "one log" problems, but I want to compare between 300 logs to see response times progressions.

Does this tool exists?

Comment: Why can't you just combine the logs together first? if that tool does what you want, combining log files is easy enough.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @PhilipHallstrom, this tool is great to find problems but not to find out when did they happen or how they did evolve. That's why I want something to compare between different logs.